# Svelte markdown blog draft mode for posts

Tags: javascript, markdown, svelte

Good afternoon. I have a website on Svelt based on markdown files. I need to make sure that posts are not published, excluded from the list of posts, if there is `published: false` in the frontmetter of these posts

Let's start with the fact that I have a utility function that pulls these posts from md files

```js
/*lib/utils/getPosts.js*/

// @ts-nocheck
export const getMarkdownPosts = async () => {
    const allPostFiles =
        import.meta.glob('/src/content/posts/*.md')
    const iterablePostFiles = Object.entries(allPostFiles)

    const allPosts = await Promise.all(
        iterablePostFiles.map(async ([path, resolver]) => {
            const { metadata } = await resolver()
            //const postPath = path.slice(11, -3)

            const postPath = path.split('/').at(-1)?.replace('.md', '')

            return {
                meta: metadata,
                path: postPath,
            }
        })
    )

    return allPosts
}
```

Then I have a server function in api/posts/+server.js

```js
/*api/posts/+server.js*/

import { getMarkdownPosts } from '$lib/utils/getPosts'
import { json } from '@sveltejs/kit'

export const GET = async () => {
  const allPosts = await getMarkdownPosts()

  const sortedPosts = allPosts.sort((a, b) => {
    return new Date(b.meta.date) - new Date(a.meta.date)
  })

  return json(sortedPosts)
}
```

Here is the load function that serves to build the article page.

```js
/*blog/[slug]/+page.js*/

export async function load({ params }){

    const post = await import(`../../../content/posts/${params.slug}.md`)
    const { title, date, categories, draft } = post.metadata
    const content = post.default

    return {
      content,
      title,
      date,
      categories
    }
}
```

I changed my server function (code below) and now it filters posts perfectly, without showing posts in the listing of posts where `published: false` is indicated in the frontmetter.

```js
/*api/posts/+server.js*/

import { getMarkdownPosts } from '$lib/utils/getPosts'
import { json } from '@sveltejs/kit'

export const GET = async () => {
  const allPosts = await getMarkdownPosts()


  const sortedPosts = allPosts.sort((a, b) => {
    return new Date(b.meta.date) - new Date(a.meta.date)
  }).filter(post => post.meta.published === true)


  return json(sortedPosts)
}
```

But an article with the specified published: false will still be available via a direct link, like http://localhost:5173/blog/first-post . And you need this article not to be on the site at all, that is, a 404 error or something like that would be displayed. Can I take this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, as I thought, everything is much simpler. Since it is quite simple to remove posts from `published: false` from the general list of articles, it was just necessary to apply `.filter(post => post.meta.published === true)`

Remove the posts altogether and output 404 instead, you can simply add such code to the load function in the file `/*blog/[slug]/+page.js*/`

```js
    if (!post || !post.metadata.published) {
        throw error(404); // Couldn't resolve the post
    }
```

So the whole code of this file looks like this:

```js
/*blog/[slug]/+page.js*/

import { error } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export async function load({ params }){

    const post = await import(`../../../content/posts/${params.slug}.md`)
    const { title, date, categories, published  } = post.metadata
    const content = post.default

    if (!post || !post.metadata.published) {
        throw error(404); // Couldn't resolve the post
    }

    return {
      content,
      title,
      date,
      categories,
      published
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Check out SvelteKit param matching!](https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/param-matchers)

The steps to implement should be something like this:

1. Change your blog route to `blog/[slug=published]/+page.js`
2. In `/src/params/`, create a function that checks for a match:

```js
export async function published(value) {
    const post = await import(`../content/posts/${params.slug}.md`)
    const { published } = post?.metadata?.published 
    return published
}
```

3. If you want a custom 404 page for missing blog posts, create a new one in `blog/[slug]/+error.svelte` (notice that the path is `slug`, not `slug=published`)

##### *Disclaimers*:

- I haven't tested the above code, so I'm not sure if you'll have any problems with the async/await for the import. If you do, you can try eagerly importing them with Vite doing something like this:

```js
const blogposts = import.meta.glob('./../lib/test/**.json', {eager: true});
```

- I was running some very similar code to what you have already for [my organisation's blog](https://kedyou.com/blog), and it was working well. However, about two months later, I replaced it with [MDsveX](https://github.com/pngwn/MDsveX). The advantage of this is you can just have your blog routes be markdown files named `+page.md`, and you can use JS imports to get functions and Svelte components into your markdown files.